# y-axis range for plotting line of best fit is way too small

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, regression

I have x and y dataframes and when I plot a scatterplot I get a pretty good result as shown below:
[image]
But when I fit the data into a regression model and plot the line of best fit, the line appears to have much higher values and it's squeezing the y-axis into a clustered mess.
[image]

How do I make the y-axis have a normal range?
Here's my code:

```
x = df\["Year"\]
y = df\["Top speed"\]

reg_prep = LinearRegression()

mod_reg = reg_prep.fit(x.to_numpy().reshape((-1,1)),y.to_numpy())
plt.scatter(x,y)

b0 = mod_reg.intercept\_
b1 = mod_reg.coef\_\[0\]
yfit = \[b0 + b1 \* xi for xi in x\]
plt.plot(x,np.array(yfit).reshape(-1,1))
plt.show()`
```

Comment: place the dataframe data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:
`plt.plot(x, model.predict(x))`